# need suggestion regrading making the specific shape

Tags: modeling, workflow

What is the best possible approach for modeling this shape. I tried alot but unable to model this kind of shape.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: The blue line is covering the important parts at the end. This really depends on how much detail you want to go for, and other things that cannot be determined from one image.